# Remove duplicates from a list and remove elements at same index in another list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have two lists, one with word and another one with word type like this

```
['fish', 'Robert', 'dog', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'Robert']
['animal', 'person', 'animal', 'object', 'animal', 'animal', 'person']
```

I need to remove duplicates in the first list and to remove the type at the same index of the word removed.

In the end I need something like this:

```
['fish', 'Robert', 'dog', 'ball', 'cat']
['animal', 'person', 'animal', 'object', 'animal']
```

How can I do that?

Comment: just do a loop and use the zip function

Comment: can you give me more details on the implementation?

Comment: For checking the duplicate, I think you can use Python's dictionary. Then if you found a duplicate, just save the index of duplicates. Then remove the items with the index from the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do a loop and use the zip function

#### Script

```py
# Input Vars
a = ['fish', 'Robert', 'dog', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'Robert']
b = ['animal', 'person', 'animal', 'object', 'animal', 'animal', 'person']

# Output Vars
c = []
d = []

# Process
for e, f in zip(a, b):
    if(e not in c):
        c.append(e)
        d.append(f)

# Print Output
print(c)
print(d)
```

#### Output

```
['fish', 'Robert', 'dog', 'ball', 'cat']
['animal', 'person', 'animal', 'object', 'animal']
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be **much** easier with dictionaries (see below)

#### With lists

```py
# Inputs
list1 = ['fish', 'Robert', 'dog', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'Robert']
list2 = ['animal', 'person', 'animal', 'object', 'animal', 'animal', 'person']

# New lists
new_list1 = []
new_list2 = []

# Loop through elements of input lists
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    # If it isn't a duplicate, append to the new lists
    if a not in new_list1:
        new_list1.append(a)
        new_list2.append(b)

# Output new lists
print(new_list1)
print(new_list2)
```

Output:

```
['fish', 'Robert', 'dog', 'ball', 'cat']
['animal', 'person', 'animal', 'object', 'animal']
```

#### With a dictionary

```py
# This uses the fact that dictionaries have unique keys, so this cancels out all the duplicates
x = dict(zip(
    ['fish', 'Robert', 'dog', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'Robert'],
    ['animal', 'person', 'animal', 'object', 'animal', 'animal', 'person']
))

# Output dictionary
print(x)

# Output keys (equivalent of new_list1)
print(list(x.keys()))

# Output values (equivalent of new_list2)
print(list(x.values()))
```

Output:

```
{'fish': 'animal', 'Robert': 'person', 'dog': 'animal', 'ball': 'object', 'cat': 'animal'}
['fish', 'Robert', 'dog', 'ball', 'cat']
['animal', 'person', 'animal', 'object', 'animal']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip two lists and use the idea of [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) that keys can be repeated only one time then return keys and values as two lists that you want:

```
lst1 = ['fish', 'Robert', 'dog', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'Robert']
lst2 = ['animal', 'person', 'animal', 'object', 'animal', 'animal', 'person']
res = dict(zip(lst1, lst2))
# res -> {'Robert': 'person','ball': 'object', 'cat': 'animal', 'dog': 'animal', 'fish': 'animal'}
list(res.keys())
# ['fish', 'Robert', 'dog', 'ball', 'cat']

list(res.values())
# ['animal', 'person', 'animal', 'object', 'animal']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `set` to de-duplicate and then use `index` to get only the first occurrence from the `word_type` list

```py
word = ['fish', 'Robert', 'dog', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'Robert']
word_type = ['animal', 'person', 'animal', 'object', 'animal', 'animal', 'person']
unique_word = list(set(word))
updated_word_type = [word_type[word.index(_)] for _ in unique_word]
```

**Output**

```
# unique_word
['dog', 'fish', 'Robert', 'ball', 'cat']

# updated_word_type
['animal', 'animal', 'person', 'object', 'animal']
```

Comment: Sure :). I also want to highlight a subtle difference between this answer (and the accepted answer) vs the answers using dictionaries. The dictionary based approach picks the "last" word + word_type combination while this (and accepted answer) picks the "first" word + word_type combination. It doesn't matter in this case, but something to be aware of